# Adding user data into firestore after Firebase Auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add User data into Cloud Firestore after using Firestore Auth when a new user is created.

```
$("#signup_btn").click(function () {
    var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email_signup").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password_signup").value;

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred=>{
        this.createNewUserData(firstname,lastname,email);
    }).catch(error =>{
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

        user.delete();
        var errorMessage = error.message;

        window.alert("Error: "+ errorMessage);
    });
});


function createNewUserData(firstname, lastname, email){
    db.collection("users").add({
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname,
        email: email
    })
        .then(function (docRef) {
            console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
}
```

The above code I've implemented is able to add user data into the firebase Auth however it doesn't add any data into the firestore database. Is there a better way to implement this function?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call another function using `this.createNewUserData`. Thus, you need to call `createNewUserData(firstname,lastname,email);` from the `then` block of `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`.

Currently,the reason that the it does not add any user data into the firestore database is that the function `createNewUserData` is not called. So, once that function is called you will get at least a call to firestore to add that user.

Comment: Its the same whether i put `this` or without. it still doesn't add the data into firestore